# Glitches appearing in Cycles but not in Eevee (Keyframes in GeometryNodes) v.3.3.1

Tags: cycles-render-engine, geometry-nodes

After finishing my first projet ever in blender 3.3.1 following Blender's Guru famous tutorial https://t.co/fthNpnRTQY
I tried to add a few animated keyframes on some nodes to go further a little for the purpose of learning more by myself.

I'm quite sure my GeometryNodes Modifiers are quite a mess but my question is essentially on some glitches appearing on the sprinkles (changing shapes) only appears when I render the final version in Cycles.

Those glitches don't not appear in the viewport, Workbench nor Eevee render...
Please check the gif comparison below, Eevee animation on the left is the wanted result (no glitches).

I'm guessing the cause might come from a bad way of connecting nodes with keyframes (I am  a newbie after all) but **why thoses sprinkles glitches only appears in Cycles**?

The full animation with unwanted glitches can be seen in this post https://twitter.com/sbgraphic/status/1579198150438707200?s=20&t=ltsoreHxq8-zl6gG4aMz5g
I finally adjust some sounds accordingly to get over with this for the fun but thoses are an unrequested glitches.

[image: Eeve - Cycles Comparison]

Scene link is here https://sb-graphicdesign.ch/cloudbox/index.php/s/R7WudeL7rhzOieD
All the best!

Comment: No idea why this happens in _Cycles_, so just a comment instead of a proper answer: your "Icing" object has 3 keyframed animations. On the _Factor_ in the "Pop_Icing-01" _Cast_ modifier, one on _Max_ of a _Random Value_ node and one on the _Axis_ Z-value of a _Vector Rotate_ node. If you remove them all (not one or a combination of two animations, it must be all three), than the glitches disappear. Don't know what to do to get rid of it while keeping the animations, sorry. Oh, and there are drivers on the sprinkles objects that throw errors, but they don't seem to be the problem there.

Comment: Thank you  for your comments, very appreciated, I will check this again. One of my guess is something is happening as the 'Icing' get distorted (influencing the 'instance on points' (?) as they become active and are not static anymore, so the random node get confused somehow ? but yeah why only in Cycles ? I might need to rebuilt those messy nodes from scratch differently as I a bit better understand how it works now.

Comment: I suspect something like that, too. But I don't know why Eevee isn't influenced by that...